# String comparsion in Arduino

Tags: string, arduino, comparison

I am working on web based Home Automation System, so my Arduino sends a request to the server and gets the following response in serial monitor, along with "loneOn", which is due to `Serial.println(r);` statement.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Oct 2014 17:46:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/html

loneOn.ltwoOn.


loneOn
```

In another case the response from the server will have loneOff, instead of loneOn, I need to decide which one it exactly is. But that's not the point right now, I am having trouble comparing the Strings. (Also the response would loop in the serial monitor, but again, that's not the point.)

This is the code for Arduino:

```cpp
#include <TextFinder.h>
#include <Dhcp.h>
#include <Dns.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <EthernetServer.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>
#include <util.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte server[] = { 192,168,137,1 } ; 
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,100);
EthernetClient client;
String response = "";
String r = "";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; 
    }

    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    }

    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting...");

    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        Serial.println("connected");

        client.println("GET /dir/ardu.php HTTP/1.1");
        client.println("Host: localhost");
        client.println();

    } 
    else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
}

void loop(){
    char c,s;

    while(client.available()) 
    {
        c = client.read();
        response = response + c; 
    }

    Serial.println(response);
    r = (response.substring(165,174));
    Serial.println(r);

    if (r == "loneOn")
        Serial.println("Light 1 is on");
}
```

The problem is:

```cpp
Serial.println(r);
if (r == "loneOn")
    Serial.println("Light 1 is on");
}
```

Doesn't work, I mean here I am comparing the String 'r' with what its real value is i.e "loneOn", which is printed exactly as it is in the serial monitor, but the if statement returns nothing. I have tried several other methods of comparing Strings but it doesn't work. I wanted to know if there's anything I am missing about the Strings.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Maybe there are unprintable trailing characters in `r`. A typical candidate would be `\n`.

Comment: I used substring function on the server response, so from "loneOn.ltwoOn." only "loneOn" is extracted. I thought the same as you said, initially, so in the response from the server i added "." so there is no confusion. The Serial.println(r) statement prints it only as "loneOn", if there was even one more character it would be "." :)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWalz there were actually a couple of "\n"s, but they were at the beginning so i didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = (response.substring(165,174));
```

I was using the wrong index, it was supposed to begin at 167. Which means there were blank spaces or "\n"s that were causing the string not to match with the given value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(r.equals("loneOn"))
{
     Serial.println("Light 1 is on");
}
```

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringEquals

Comment: Actually, i found the problem. It was in the substring statement.
    r = (response.substring(165,174));
I was using the wrong index, it was supposed to begin at 167, its like what @Michael Walz said, what i missed was the fact that it was at the beginning of the string and not at the end.
And previously i did try the method you proposed.
Thanks for your response.